# html sign up form not saving data in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

I have written a very basic HTML sign-up form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>

<form name="reg" action="code_exec.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  <table width="274" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div align="center">
          <?php 
          // $remarks=$_GET['remarks'];
          if (!isset($_GET['remarks']))
          {
            echo 'Register Here';
          }
          if (isset($_GET['remarks']) && $_GET['remarks']=='success')
          {
            echo 'Registration Success';
          }
          ?>  
        </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="95"><div align="right">First Name:</div></td>
        <td width="171"><input type="text" name="fname" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div align="right">Last Name:</div></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lname" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div align="right">Gender:</div></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="gender" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div align="right">Address:</div></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="address" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div align="right">Contact No.:</div></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="contact" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div align="right">Username:</div></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div align="right">Password:</div></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="password" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div align="right"></div></td>
        <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using PHP to connect my HTML page to a MySQL database on XAMPP server installed/configured locally.

I have divided my connection, and data storage logic across 2 different `.php` files:

### connection.php

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "amitesh";
$mysql_password = "amitesh";
$mysql_database = "sign_up_form";
$prefix = "";

$bd = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysqli_select_db($mysql_database,$bd) or die("Could not select database");
?>
```

### code_exec.php

```
<?php
session_start();

include('connection.php');

$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$mname=$_POST['mname'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$contact=$_POST['contact'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

mysqli_query($bd, "INSERT INTO member(fname, lname, gender, address, contact, username, password)VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$mname', '$address', '$contact','$username', '$password')");

header("location: index.php?remarks=success");

mysqli_close($bd);
```

After I insert data in the page, when I click on the "submit" button, it shows me the code of the `code_exec.php` file instead of storing the data in MySQL.

I did see couple of StackOverflow posts about this, but none of them seem to offer a working solution for my problem.

Why could this be happening?

Comment: did you start the Apache in XAMP server?

Comment: Never store plain text passwords! Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security.  Also, you are **wide open to** [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: @Gopalakrishnan, yes, the Apache in XAMP server in started.

Comment: @Miilan, thank you for your insight on best practise. However, I am just trying to do a testing, its obvious that going forward, when I start things in real time, it would be secured from all the front.

Comment: If I had a nickel...

Comment: When you say that you are shown the code of the page, do you mean the raw PHP code? Like, when you navigate to the page, you are shown the `<?php` tag, etc?

Comment: @Toastrackenigma, yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Introduction

If the `<?php` tags and **actual website code** are being displayed on the page, then there are only two scenarios:

1. XAMPP is not working, or;
2. You are not navigating to a file at the web address [127.0.0.1](http://127.0.0.1).

Since you have confirmed that XAMPP is running, I will cover scenario two, which is the most likely.

### You are not navigating to a file at the web address 127.0.0.1

Inside of your XAMPP installation, you should find a folder called `htdocs`. This is the folder which should contain **any** websites that you make, and **all** of their PHP code - it acts as the root directory of your web server (if you were using a dedicated server, it is the equivalent of `/var/www/html/`). The server only processes files which are contained within that folder.

If your files are not inside of that folder, move them into it (and delete / move to a different folder any files that where previously in that directory).

Next, you can't just open those files in your web browser once they are in the folder - you have to navigate to them via your locally hosted website.

Go to the URL [127.0.0.1](http://127.0.0.1]) or [localhost](http://localhost) to visit your locally hosted website. This is only accessible to you, on your computer, while XAMPP is running, and it displays the documents in the `htdocs` folder. You can choose a file in that list to visit it, and it should now run on your web server.

### Summary

From now on, it should be fairly easy for you to work with files on your local web server. Of course, there could still be a PHP error in your code (I checked over it quickly - everything appears to be fine, but I could have missed something) - if that is the case and you get stuck with debugging, you can always ask another question here on StackOverflow!

As a bonus, you should be able to visit [127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/](http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/) with XAMPP running to manage your MySQL tables and databases via a web interface.

Answer (score 0):

> note that you can not use php builtin server in this case. because your index.php file not is a front controller. copy your code in XAMPP htdocs directory and access your code with localhost/your_directory_name url.

and note that you have an error in your connection.php file.

in mysqli_select_db() function first parameter is mysqli link and second parameter is dbname.

replace

```
mysqli_select_db($mysql_database,$bd) or die("Could not select database");
```

with

```
mysqli_select_db($bd, $mysql_database) or die("Could not select database");
```

Comment: made the changes, but no success.

Comment: note that you can not use php builtin server in this case. because your index.php file not is a front controller.
copy your code in XAMPP htdocs directory and access your code with http://localhost/your_directory_name url.

Comment: I have removed index.php reference from the code_exec.php, I do not have any file with that name. Yes, I have already put my wesite folder inside "htdoc", just to let you know that, I have installed the XAMPP server in my USB drive, and when ever I work with it, I attach the USb first to my machine,and then start working with it, so even in this case, it would be "localhost", right? I did try to launch the website as localhost/<folder_name>,but it gave me "forbidden" error, not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I am trying to use below
/localhost/D:/xampp/htdocs/folder/index.html

pretty sure, not the right way, please suggest further

Comment: I have no idea about XAMPP installation in USB drive. Install XAMPP in your PC and try this URL localhost/<folder_name>. It works properly.

Comment: To cross check, I typed "localhost", and the web browser picked up my website from "htdoc" folder that resides in my USB.

Answer (score 0):

Try to build your connection like this:

Mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database) or die(mysqli_error)

Comment: I made that change, but no use, I am pretty sure that I am missing on some silly point,but couldn't get hold of it.